# Pandas and Numpy Import error when using Apache2, Anaconda and Django

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi

Am getting the following error - Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Standalone and via Django, without Apache2 integration - the code work likes charm, however things start to fall when used with Apache2. It refuses to import pandas or numpy giving one error after another.

I am using Apache2, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, Python 3.5 and Anaconda 2.3.0

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/api/users/0/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Exception Location: /home/fractaluser/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>, line 18
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg',
 '/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/html/cgmvp']
Server time:    Fri, 9 Jun 2017 11:12:37 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't force mod_wsgi built with the system Python version to use a Python virtual environment built for a different Python version, nor different Python installation. That is what it appears you are doing. You would need to uninstall mod_wsgi and install it from source code, compiling it against the Anaconda Python distribution. Best to use the `pip` install method and follow steps to integrate it into existing Apache installation. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Also see the following documentation for setting up a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi, as it appears you aren't doing that in the recommended way either.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

First task though is to reinstall mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using apache2 with mod_wsgi python 3.6 envinronmet 64, the version numpy used was 1.13, only change the version with previous and worked !!.

```
pip3 install numpy==1.12
```